# Using an awk field separator on part of a line, until some unique character

Tags: awk, sh

Let's say I have an input textFile.txt containing:

```
0.3340     0.2333  0.1029     .0349  .2302 [ blah blah ] 
0.2223     0.2343  0.2394     .4395  .7943 [ blah2 blah2 ]
```

and there is variable amount of whitespace between the numbers.

and I want to output:

```
0.334,0.2333,0.1029,.0349,.2302 [ blah blah ]
0.2223,0.2343,0.2394,.4395,.7943 [ blah2 blah2 ]
```

for further processing.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' textFile.txt
```

How can I combine the field separator I want with a search for the left bracket, and tell it to output what's after the left bracket un-modified?

Answer (score 5):

As per the sample input, you want commas between fields that are separated by *more* than one space.  If that is the case:

```
$ awk -F'  +' '$1=$1' OFS=, text.txt
0.3340,0.2333,0.1029,.0349,.2302 [ blah blah ] 
0.2223,0.2343,0.2394,.4395,.7943 [ blah2 blah2 ]
```

How it works:

- `-F'  +'`

  This tells awk to treat two or more blanks as the field separator.
- `$1=$1`

  This makes awk think that the line has been changed.  Consequently, awk will reformat the line on the output with the new field separator.
- `OFS=,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the output field separator.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]?\\.[0-9]+|\\[[^][]+\\]' \
      '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i == NF? ORS : ",") }' file
```

- `FPAT` - built-in variable; pattern defining field value

The output:

```
0.3340,0.2333,0.1029,.0349,.2302,[ blah blah ]
0.2223,0.2343,0.2394,.4395,.7943,[ blah2 blah2 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use left-bracket (actually, "space+bracket") 
as the field separator, and replace spaces in the first 
field:

```
gawk -F' \\[' -v OFS=' [' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,",",$1); print }'
```

Requires GNU awk, I believe.